# Question about multipole expansion of electrostatic potential?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, multipole-expansion

If I take a certain dipole and by dipole I mean that two charges of opposite sign differentiated by very small distance. And if I take the formula of multipole  expansion of potential then I see no other term except the dipole moment exists because everything except the dipole becomes zero. Now if I have a sphere whose charge density is not quite uniform (ie $\rho(r,\theta)= krcos\theta$, where $r$ and $\theta$ are spherical polar coordinates) but I know that it's two sides have same but opposite amount of charges then should I treat it as a dipole and by the expansion only the survives or do I have to make precise calculations as the result is unpredictable?

Comment: What do you mean by “I see movement”? And can you please break your second very long sentence down into multiple sentences that are easier to understand?

Comment: @G.Smith i am sorry I was voice typing that came out wrong so I edited it.

Comment: @G.Smith is it ok now?

Comment: No charge distribution can truly have only a dipole moment term in its multipole expansion--the higher moment terms might get as small as you want but one cannot have a charge distribution with only a dipole moment term.

Comment: @DvijMankad are you sure an exact dipole has higher order terms. Can you give reference to me as i know to compute till quadrupole moment.

Comment: @DvijMankad When we derive the potential for an exact dipole then the dipole term only survives as we can derive the potential for dipole as $f(r,\theta)$ right?

Comment: @Nobodyrecognizeable I meant that an exact dipole is a mathematical idealization but cannot be realized with a physical charge distribution. I don't have a copy with me right now so I cannot find the relevant quote but it is beautifully explained in _Chapter $3^\text{rd}$, Introduction to Electrodynamics ($3^\text{rd}$ Edition), D.J. Griffiths_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This distribution has no net charge, but it has a dipole moment, a quadrupole moment, an octupole moment, etc. If you are approximating the potential, you can keep as few or as many of these as you need for the accuracy you desire. If you want an exact result, don’t use the multipole expansion.

The result is not “unpredictable”. The dipole term will decrease as $1/r^2$, the quadrupole as $1/r^3$, etc. Far away, the terms get smaller and smaller. But close in, they are all important.

If you take oppositely charged point particles and bring them together while letting the product of the charge and the separation stay constant, you get a pure dipole with no other moments. But your spherical distribution is not a pure dipole. It is dipole + higher moments.

Comment: If we have a dipole then quadrupole and monopole moments have zero values ; dipole moment exists but does that say octupole moment and so on all are zero?

Comment: If you take oppositely charged point particles and bring them together while letting the product of the charge and the separation stay constant, you get a pure dipole with no other moments. But your spherical distribution is not a pure dipole. It is dipole + higher moments.

Comment: great ! You should add that in the answer

Comment: You asked, you got. Perhaps you would consider marking the answer as accepted?

Comment: thanks for all the help.

Comment: You’re welcome, and thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: @G.Smith Nice explanation but please could you let me know why the multiple expansion work only for far away points and not near points. What if i need to find the potential at a near point... Wouldn't the answer still be given by the dipole term ( if say the dipole term gives the answer for far away points) . Or is the problem that at near point the termination of the expansion series will give a poor approximation. Or there is something else in why does the multiple expansion work only for far away points...

Comment: @Shashaank The multipole expansion is valid at all positions, but generally it is *useful* only far from the source, where the $1/r^\ell$ dependence of the terms means that only the first nonzero term is important. Close to the source, *all* the terms can be important and you must sum an infinite series.

Comment: @G.Smith thanks I get that, at a near point one will need to add many terms to get a good result whereas at a far point only the dipole(say if it's non zero)term alone will do .. But while deriving the multipole series we take a binomial expansion in just the 1st step... Won't that render the series completely useless beyond a certain near point ( where the binomial expansion fails), thus making the series applicable only to points points beyond certain limit ( where the series will totally diverge). Is my understanding wrong. Kindly let me know because you said it's valid *at all points*

Comment: @Shashaank I wasn’t thinking about the possibility you raised that the series might diverge. I suppose it’s possible that it might not be valid at points that are too close. I’ve never investigated this. But I don’t see any *physical* reason why it would diverge.

Comment: @Shashaank A little googling seems to indicate that it does diverge, so I was wrong.

Comment: @Shashaank [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) has this to say: “In principle, a multipole expansion provides an exact description of the potential and generally converges under two conditions: (1) if the sources (e.g. charges) are localized close to the origin and the point at which the potential is observed is far from the origin; or (2) the reverse, i.e., if the sources are located far from the origin and the potential is observed close to the origin.”

Comment: @G.Smith yes the convergence of the series would depend on the convergence of the binomial expansion ( or on the series of legendre polynomial). So is the final status this ( in case 1 of your last comment) - " At very far away points, the potential can be given by just a single term of the series, the first non zero one ( say the the dipole).. As you move closer towards the configuration you would need to sum more and more terms to get a good approximation. If you go still closer you reach a point beyond which the series fail to converge howsoever many terms  you may add

Comment: @G.Smith let me know if you this is  correct or you see anything wrong in it. And thanks for the wikipesia thing.. I wasn't aware of the case 2)

Comment: @Shashaank Yes, I agree with what you wrote.

Comment: @G.Smith  thanks for helping me out